# Determinant of Vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Is posible obtain the determinant of any vector?.How I will be able to obtain the determinant of any vector $v=[v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n]\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: $v=[v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n]$ is in $\mathbb{R^n}$, not in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The determinant is defined only for matrices at least $2 x 2$

Comment: I hope what Federica pointed out is only a typo. In any case if you are asking this because you see it ("determinant of a vector") referred to somewhere, please give an indication where you saw it. Sometimes things make more sense in context.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: the determinant is also defined for matrices of size $1\times 1$: $\det [a] = a$.

Comment: @WillieWong: In that case it's the determinant of a scalar.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra The determinant is defined for square matrices of any (finite) size (and over a commutative ring). Including sizes $0\times0$ (in which case the determinant is $1$), and $1\times1$ (in which case the determinant, like the trace, has the same value as the unique entry of the matrix).

Answer (score 5):

If you identify a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with the linear mapping $$
  F_v \,:\, \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n \,:\, x \to (v^T\cdot x, 0, \ldots 0)^T \text{,}
$$
i.e. if you identify the vector $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ with the matrix $$
  F_v = \begin{pmatrix}v_1 &\ldots &v_n\\ 0&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&\ldots&0\end{pmatrix} \text{,}
$$
you can say that $$
  \det v = \det F_v = \begin{cases}
    v_1 &\text{if $n=1$} \\
    0   &\text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$
Though whether that's particularly helpful is a different question..

Answer (score 3):

Determinants are defined for square matrices, only. If you are trying to use the determinant of a vector (and $n\neq1$) then you are somehow on a very wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the determinant is defined not as a function of a vector, but rather as a multilinear function of $n$ vectors in $n$-space, in other words $\det : \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and is multilinear. In this setup it doesn't make much sense talking about $\det(v)$ for some $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, because $\det$ was built to receive as it's input $n$ vectors instead of just one.

If you insist in defining the determinant of a vector however, one possibility would be to talk about the *new* function obtained defining $f_v: \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by setting:

$$f_v(w_1, \dots, w_{n-1})=\det(v, w_1\dots, w_{n-1})$$

So that we would me mapping $v \mapsto \det(v, \cdot, \dots, \cdot)$, that's probably a common approach when we deal with tensors in general: if we understand tensors as multilinear maps, then if we give just one argument to the tensor it gives us back a multilinear map that can receive one less input, because one of the inputs was fixed, in that framework $\det$ is a tensor and giving just one vector to it gives back a new function of $n-1$ vectors.